# Is it possible to create a bootable USB flash drive with multiple OS’s to install?

Tags: macos, mac, usb, install

I’m a computer tech and I heard it’s possible to create a multi OS boot drive for Mac OS.

How would I go about that?

Let’s say I wanted Sierra, High Sierra, and Mojave on a 32GB USB USB flash drive. How can I do that?

Comment: If you have a Mac running Mojave or earlier, you can still use [DiskMaker X](https://diskmakerx.com) to create a multi-boot flash drive.  It may run on later OS, I don't know.

Comment: This has come up before. If the answers there don't help you to solve the problem, please edit the question to add details about what you tried and how it failed so the hold on the question can be reviewed.